# I am creating a boggle scrambler in python using turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-turtle

I am trying to create a boggle came but the display shows brackets. Please help me remove **ALL** the brackets and apostrophes when I run the program
here is my numpy grid array:
Im pretty new to python and I tried: `str(grid).lstrip('[').rstrip(']')`

````
grid = np.array([['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',]])```
````

and here's a print output:

```
[['M' 'Z' 'S' 'T']
 ['Y' 'U' 'C' 'R']
 ['H' 'G' 'D' 'A']
 ['O' 'E' 'E' 'W']]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show what you have tried so far to solve _your_ problem?

Comment: Hey @Timus I have updated my question to show what I tried

Comment: `lstrip`, `rstrip` only works at the borders of the string. Try `str(grid).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "clean" print out (i.e. without the string markers `'`) then try the following:

```
grid = np.array([['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x',]])

print('\n'.join(' '.join(entry for entry in row) for row in grid))
```

Output:

```
x x x x 
x x x x 
x x x x 
x x x x
```

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) to understand how `join` works.